# Mediasoup client on react native crashes when transport.on('connect' calls callback()

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc, mediasoup

Am using `mediasoup` for video conferencing, but on the connection stages, where `transport.produce()`
invokes `transport.on('connect'` event when i execute callback from `transport.on('connect` the application crashes

```
producerTransport.on(
  'connect',
  async function ({dtlsParameters}, callback, errback) {
    await Request('connectTransport', {
      dtlsParameters,
      transport_id: data.id,
    })
      .then(data => {
        callback();//crashes the application when called, 
      })
      .catch(errback);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i wasnt setting permission properly

Locate your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```